# pm2 start npm <processName>.out.log no content

Tags: node.js, npm, process, pm2

I use Next.js to develop a project, and run it by pm2: `pm2 start npm -- start`

I can see a file named `<processName>.out.log`，but that has no content in it.

```
export function getServerSideProps (ctx) {
  console.log('-------test----------')
  return {
    props: {}
  }
}
```

How can I get logs without much efforts?

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4749#issuecomment-647491984

I did not find related issues online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var exec = require('child_process').spawn

exec(
    'npm',
    ['run', 'start'], 
    {
    shell: true,
    stdio: 'inherit'
})
```

this can get logs contains process stdout

Comment: require('child_process').exec not